# Why doesn't "sequential download" cause files in a torrent to be downloaded one by one with PicoTorrent?

Tags: windows, download

I am downloading a [torrent file](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stackexchange_archive.torrent) with [PicoTorrent](https://github.com/picotorrent/picotorrent) on Windows 10. Before the download started, I selected "sequential download". I thought it meant that files would be downloaded one by one. However, that's not the case, as shown in the screenshot below. Why?

[image]

Peers:

[image]

Comment: Because, if one file started it won't stop even if you've later selected sequential downloading. If you add the torrent in paused mode, and then select sequential downloading and start it it will work. IIRC

Comment: @Gantendo Thanks,  I selected "sequential download before the download started.

Comment: https://github.com/picotorrent/picotorrent/issues/776

Comment: Does your torrent software have an “overall parts” view? If yes, what does it show? What’s the torrent’s piece (block) size? Torrents pieces do not stop/start at file boundaries.

Comment: @DanielB thanks, you're right https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbxAM.png you're welcome to post it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sequential download refers to the torrent in its entirety. You can observe overall progress on the [“Overview” tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbxAM.png).

However, this cannot explain what you are seeing. Normally, my explanation would be that torrent contents are split into pieces of fixed length (4 MiB in this case), with piece boundaries not necessarily aligning with file boundaries. However, under the hood, this particular torrent actually has padding files to make sure that does not happen. The file list is also actually ordered alphabetically, so that’s not it either.

Instead, the problem is probably with how the sequential download mode is implemented in *libtorrent*, the underlying library ([Source](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/blob/master/docs/streaming.rst)):

> `sequential_download` will simply wait until a queue slot opens up, and request the next piece in the sequence. This mechanism is even simpler than the classic "rarest-first" algorithm; it does a good job of keeping request queues full, thus saturating available download bandwidth; and pieces do arrive roughly in-order. However, it's sub-optimal for streaming: piece 0 may be requested from a slow peer, and fast peers will get requests for later-index pieces instead of retrying more-critical ones.

You probably had some bad luck with certain pieces.

There could also be unexpected interaction between web seeds and sequential download mode.

Comment: And what if you are connected to a peer who does not have any blocks of the file you are downloading? Maybe the software just ignores the sequential setting in that case.

Comment: @Gantendo Well, it’s a _request_ queue, so it will probably just stall eventually.